# Can't add Jupyter Notebook to project in IBM Cloud's Watson Studio

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I can't add a Jupyter notebook to a project in IBM Watson Studio.  I open the project, select "Add to Project", choose Notebook, then inside I give it a name, description, runtime, and the "Create Notebook" button is still grayed out (disabled).  There's nothing else to specify.  I've tried deleting and re-adding Watson Studio to no avail.  I've tried opening a Jupyter notebook in another of my projects, and it doesn't open..."busy" cursor just spins.  Can someone please help me?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the browser Press F12 to turn on the debugger. Refresh the page. Review any errors.

Comment: Do you have Analytics or any other service associated with the project in which the Jupyter notebook is created?

Answer (score 0):

- On the projects home page, under the Assets tab, 'Add to Project' can be noticed.
- Click on that button and it shall bring the 'Choose Asset Type'.
- Choose Notebook and it shall open a new window. Provide the book name and default configuration and then create.
  [image]
  Picture showing the Notebook creation from IBM Watson Studio

Hope this helps. !

Comment: when i clicked 'add to project' , there is no button showing notbook. Even there are only 5 choices.